# numpy covariance between two columns in a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the covariance between two columns in a matrix. I'm getting the following error:''numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'numpy''

I'm using a for loop and incrementing by 2, because I have 20 columns total and 10 sets. 1st set = column 1,2 --> 2nd set = column 3,4 ect..

I'm referencing this: https://www.pythonprogramming.in/calculates-the-covariance-between-columns-of-dataframe-in-pandas.html

```
import pandas
import numpy

data = pandas.read_excel("data.xlsx", header=None)
datanpy = pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy(data)

for i in range (0, 20, 2):
    x = datanpy[i]
    y = datanpy[i + 1]
    covariance = x.numpy.cov(y)
    print(covariance)
```

Comment: `datanpy = data.to_numpy()`  -https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy

Comment: pandas has built-in covariance function as well `data.cov()`.

Comment: How would I take the covariance between two columnswith that function?

Comment: Also, correct call for `numpy.cov` is `numpy.cov(x,y)`. You can also do `numpy.cov(data.iloc[:,i], data.iloc[:,i+1])` without sourcing `to_numpy()`.

Comment: @stormakt `data.iloc[:, i:i+2].cov()`

Comment: Ok thank you. Is it possible to plot the covariance values on a scatter plot using matplotlib.pyplot? I want to plot all 10 values for the 20columns on one scatter plot